# Conic sections appendix

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

My questions concerns a chapter in Michael Spivak's math book Calculus. On page 81, Spivak talks about finding a coordinate axes for a plane *P* that intersects a cone. What I don't understand is the part where he talks about a point in that plane having a certain first coordinate with respect to the newly created axes; he labels this as *x*. This same point has *αx+β* its first coordinate relative to the standard axes with which we are familiar. I don't understand where he got the *αx+β*. I really hope someone clears this up for me.

**Here is a quote from that page dealing with conic sections:**
"Now we have to choose coordinate axes in the plane P. We can choose L as the
first axis, measuring distances from the intersection Q with the horizontal plane
(Figure 5); for the second axis we just choose the line through Q parallel to our
original second axis. If the first coordinate of a point in P with respect to these
axes is x, then the first coordinate of this point with respect to the original axes
can be written in the form
*αx+β*
for some *β*. On the other hand, if the second coordinate of the point with
respect to these axes is y, then y is also the second coordinate with respect to the
original axes."

Comment: This looks like a linear transformation: a scaling plus a translation. However, not everyone that comes across this question has the book in hand. If you include (preferably in text, not pictures) the relevant parts of the book, you might get more answers.

Comment: Do you mean the quote them?